Edit table of content
I'm writing an article. How can I customise the List of Figures to appear as
Part A, Fig 1 ...........  4
Part B, Fig 2 ...........  5 

\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,fleqn,english]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\graphicspath{-
    {../graphics/}
}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=blue,
    urlcolor=blue,
    citecolor=blue
}

\begin{document}
    
\newpage
\tableofcontents
    
\newpage
\listoffigures\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures}
\newpage
\listoftables\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Tables}

\newpage
\part{Structured Literature Review} \label{}

\section{Section One}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    {\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image}}
    \hfill
    \caption{Figure 1}
    \label{fig1:Figure 1}
\end{figure}
    
\newpage
\part{Structured Literature Review} \label{}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    {\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image}} 
    \hfill
    \caption{Figure 2}
    \label{fig2:Figure 2}
\end{figure}
    
\end{document}



Just a tip: if you use an image from the mwe package, e.g. example-image instead of TNM_stages.png etc., other people will be able to test your code.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, I have added the sample image. Thanks

The idea is to use an image like example-image, which people will already have as part of their latex distribution. This way they don't have to download any additional files.

Do you have one to share, or how can I access it? I am new to LATeX, so I am not sure how to go about that.

Replace example_fig with example-image@KelechiIgwe

In your intended list of figure: Where are the phrases "Fig 1" and "Fig 2" to come from? Are these the figures' captions? Are these the figures' numbers, prefixed with the phrase "Fig" ?

@UlrichDiez, Fig is prefixed while "1" and "2" are the actual figure numbers from Latex.

So you don't want the captions of figures to occur in the list, only their (prefixed) numbers?

\part{Structured Literature Review} \label{}
[...]
\part{Structured Literature Review} \label{}
yields two attempts at defining the nameless cross-referencing-label which in turn results in the messages
LaTeX Warning: Label `' multiply defined.
and
LaTeX Warning: There were multiply-defined labels.

Seems, with
\graphicspath{-
    {../graphics/}
}

one directory for searching images is -. Check whether a directory name - is correct syntax with the computer platform in use. The author of this answer didn't check what effect such a directory name might have regarding the Kpathsea-library.

With
\listoffigures\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures}
in the table of contents both the hyperlink and the page number of the entry for the list of figures point to the last page of the list of figures, not to the first page of the list of figures. As long as the list of figures fits on a single page, this is not relevant, but in case the list of figures is long and spans more than one page, you probably don't like to be pointed/directed towards the list of figure's last page. Probably the bet is a bit safer when adding the entry to the table of contents via the list of figures, s.th. like this:
\addtocontents{lof}{\string\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures}\protected@file@percent}%



Probably hooking into \l@figure does the trick.

With TeXLive 2020, 2021, 2022 this can be done like this:
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,fleqn,english]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\graphicspath{%
    {../graphics/}%
}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=blue,
    urlcolor=blue,
    citecolor=blue
}

\makeatletter
\addtocontents{lof}{\string\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures}\protected@file@percent}%
\addtocontents{lot}{\string\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Tables}\protected@file@percent}%
\renewcommand\thepart{\Alph{part}}%
\DeclareRobustCommand\LofLofPart[2]{#1#2}%
\DeclareRobustCommand\GobbleLofPart[2]{#2}%
\DeclareRobustCommand\LofPart[2]{#2}%
\addtocontents{lof}{\string\let\string\LofPart=\string\LofLofPart}%
\AtEndDocument{\addtocontents{lof}{\string\let\string\LofPart=\string\GobbleLofPart}}%
\renewcommand*\thefigure{\LofPart{Part \thepart, Fig.\null~}{\arabic{figure}}}% Probably \figurename instead of "Fig.\null"
% Original definition:
%  \@dottedtocline{<number of sectioning level>}{<indenting>}{<width of number>}{<text>}{<page number>}%
%\renewcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline {1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}%
\renewcommand*\l@figure{\rearrange \@dottedtocline {1}{1.5em}{6.9em}}%
\newcommand\rearrange[6]{%
  % #1 = \@dottedtocline
  % #2 = number of sectioning level
  % #3 = indenting
  % #4 = width of number of figure
  % #5 = text
  % #6 = page number
  % ; text is of pattern
  %   \hyper@linkstart{link}{\Hy@tocdestname}%
  %   {%
  %     \numberline
  %     {\LofPart {Part A, Fig.\hbox{}\nobreakspace{}}{1}}%
  %     {\ignorespaces Caption of figure 1}%
  %   }%
  %   \hyper@linkend 
  #1{#2}{#3}{#4}{\rearrangeB #5}{#6}%
}%
\newcommand\rearrangeB[5]{%
  % #1 = \hyper@linkstart
  % #2 = link
  % #3 = \Hy@tocdestname
  % #4 = \numberline
  %      {\LofPart {Part A, Fig.\hbox{}\nobreakspace{}}{1}}%
  %      {\ignorespaces Caption of figure 1}%
  % #5 = \hyper@linkend
  #1{#2}{#3}{\rearrangeC #4}#5%
}%
\newcommand\rearrangeC[3]{%
  % #1 = \numberline
  % #2 = \LofPart {Part A, Fig.\hbox{}\nobreakspace{}}{1}
  % #3 = \ignorespaces Caption of figure 1
  #1{#2}{\ignorespaces}%
}%
\makeatother


\begin{document}
    
\newpage
\tableofcontents
    
\newpage
\listoffigures
\newpage
\listoftables

\newpage
\part{Structured Literature Review}

\section{Section One}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    {\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image}}
    \hfill
    \caption{Caption of figure 1}
    \label{fig1:Figure 1}
\end{figure}
    
\newpage
\part{Structured Literature Review}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    {\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image}} 
    \hfill
    \caption{Caption of figure 2}
    \label{fig2:Figure 2}
\end{figure}
    
\end{document}



With TeXLive 2023, 2024 the way in which hyperref creates links for lines of table of contents/of list of figures/of list of tables has changed so that with these probably the following does the trick:
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,fleqn,english]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\graphicspath{%
    {../graphics/}%
}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=blue,
    urlcolor=blue,
    citecolor=blue
}

\makeatletter
\addtocontents{lof}{\string\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures}\protected@file@percent}%
\addtocontents{lot}{\string\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Tables}\protected@file@percent}%
\renewcommand\thepart{\Alph{part}}%
\DeclareRobustCommand\LofLofPart[2]{#1#2}%
\DeclareRobustCommand\GobbleLofPart[2]{#2}%
\DeclareRobustCommand\LofPart[2]{#2}%
\addtocontents{lof}{\string\let\string\LofPart=\string\LofLofPart}%
\AtEndDocument{\addtocontents{lof}{\string\let\string\LofPart=\string\GobbleLofPart}}%
\renewcommand*\thefigure{\LofPart{Part \thepart, Fig.\null~}{\arabic{figure}}}% Probably \figurename instead of "Fig.\null"
% Original definition:
%  \@dottedtocline{<number of sectioning level>}{<indenting>}{<width of number>}{<text>}{<page number>}%
%\renewcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline {1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}%
\renewcommand*\l@figure{\rearrange \@dottedtocline {1}{1.5em}{6.9em}}%
\newcommand\rearrange[6]{%
  % #1 = \@dottedtocline
  % #2 = number of sectioning level
  % #3 = indenting
  % #4 = width of number of figure
  % #5 = text
  % #6 = page number
  % ; text is of pattern
  %   \Hy@toclinkstart
  %   {%
  %     \numberline
  %     {\LofPart {Part A, Fig.\hbox{}\nobreakspace {}}{1}}%
  %     {\ignorespaces Caption of figure 1}%
  %   }%
  %   \Hy@toclinkend 
  #1{#2}{#3}{#4}{\rearrangeB #5}{#6}%
}%
\newcommand\rearrangeB[3]{%
  % #1 = \Hy@toclinkstart 
  % #2 = \numberline 
  %      {\LofPart {Part A, Fig.\hbox{}\nobreakspace{}}{1}}%
  %      {\ignorespaces Caption of figure 1}%
  % #3 = \Hy@toclinkend 
  #1{\rearrangeC#2}#3%
}%
\newcommand\rearrangeC[3]{%
  % #1 = \numberline
  % #2 = \LofPart {Part A, Fig.\hbox{}\nobreakspace{}}{1}
  % #3 = \ignorespaces Caption of figure 1
  #1{#2}{\ignorespaces}%
}%
\makeatother


\begin{document}
    
\newpage
\tableofcontents
    
\newpage
\listoffigures
\newpage
\listoftables

\newpage
\part{Structured Literature Review}

\section{Section One}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    {\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image}}
    \hfill
    \caption{Caption of figure 1}
    \label{fig1:Figure 1}
\end{figure}
    
\newpage
\part{Structured Literature Review}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    {\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image}} 
    \hfill
    \caption{Caption of figure 2}
    \label{fig2:Figure 2}
\end{figure}
    
\end{document}




If you want the captions to occur in the list of figures,

with TeXLive 2020, 2021, 2022 you can try this:

\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,fleqn,english]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\graphicspath{%
    {../graphics/}%
}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=blue,
    urlcolor=blue,
    citecolor=blue
}

\makeatletter
\addtocontents{lof}{\string\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures}\protected@file@percent}%
\addtocontents{lot}{\string\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Tables}\protected@file@percent}%
\renewcommand\thepart{\Alph{part}}%
\DeclareRobustCommand\LofLofPart[2]{#1#2}%
\DeclareRobustCommand\GobbleLofPart[2]{#2}%
\DeclareRobustCommand\LofPart[2]{#2}%
\addtocontents{lof}{\string\let\string\LofPart=\string\LofLofPart}%
\AtEndDocument{\addtocontents{lof}{\string\let\string\LofPart=\string\GobbleLofPart}}%
\renewcommand*\thefigure{\LofPart{Part \thepart, \figurename~}{\arabic{figure}}}%
% Original definition:
%  \@dottedtocline{<number of sectioning level>}{<indenting>}{<width of number>}{<text>}{<page number>}%
%\renewcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline {1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}%
\renewcommand*\l@figure{\rearrange \@dottedtocline {1}{0em}{0em}}%
\newcommand\rearrange[6]{%
  % #1 = \@dottedtocline
  % #2 = number of sectioning level
  % #3 = indenting
  % #4 = width of number of figure
  % #5 = text
  % #6 = page number
  % ; text is of pattern
  %   \hyper@linkstart{link}{\Hy@tocdestname}%
  %   {%
  %     \numberline
  %     {\LofPart {Part A, Figure\nobreakspace{}}{1}}%
  %     {\ignorespaces Caption of figure 1}%
  %   }%
  %   \hyper@linkend 
  #1{#2}{#3}{#4}{\rearrangeB #5}{#6}%
}%
\newcommand\rearrangeB[5]{%
  % #1 = \hyper@linkstart
  % #2 = link
  % #3 = \Hy@tocdestname
  % #4 = \numberline
  %      {\LofPart {Part A, Figure\nobreakspace{}}{1}}%
  %      {\ignorespaces Caption of figure 1}%
  % #5 = \hyper@linkend
  #1{#2}{#3}{\rearrangeC #4}#5%
}%
\newcommand\rearrangeC[3]{%
  % #1 = \numberline
  % #2 = \LofPart {Part A, Figure\nobreakspace{}}{1}
  % #3 = \ignorespaces Caption of figure 1
  #1{}{#2: #3}%
}%
\makeatother


\begin{document}
    
\newpage
\tableofcontents
    
\newpage
\listoffigures
\newpage
\listoftables

\newpage
\part{Structured Literature Review}

\section{Section One}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    {\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image}}
    \hfill
    \caption{Caption of figure 1}
    \label{fig1:Figure 1}
\end{figure}
    
\newpage
\part{Structured Literature Review}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    {\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image}} 
    \hfill
    \caption{Caption of figure 2}
    \label{fig2:Figure 2}
\end{figure}
    
\end{document}



with TeXLive 2023, 2024 you can try this:

\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,fleqn,english]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\graphicspath{%
    {../graphics/}%
}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=blue,
    urlcolor=blue,
    citecolor=blue
}

\makeatletter
\addtocontents{lof}{\string\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures}\protected@file@percent}%
\addtocontents{lot}{\string\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Tables}\protected@file@percent}%
\renewcommand\thepart{\Alph{part}}%
\DeclareRobustCommand\LofLofPart[2]{#1#2}%
\DeclareRobustCommand\GobbleLofPart[2]{#2}%
\DeclareRobustCommand\LofPart[2]{#2}%
\addtocontents{lof}{\string\let\string\LofPart=\string\LofLofPart}%
\AtEndDocument{\addtocontents{lof}{\string\let\string\LofPart=\string\GobbleLofPart}}%
\renewcommand*\thefigure{\LofPart{Part \thepart, \figurename~}{\arabic{figure}}}%
% Original definition:
%  \@dottedtocline{<number of sectioning level>}{<indenting>}{<width of number>}{<text>}{<page number>}%
%\renewcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline {1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}%
\renewcommand*\l@figure{\rearrange \@dottedtocline {1}{0em}{0em}}%
\newcommand\rearrange[6]{%
  % #1 = \@dottedtocline
  % #2 = number of sectioning level
  % #3 = indenting
  % #4 = width of number of figure
  % #5 = text
  % #6 = page number
  % ; text is of pattern
  %   \Hy@toclinkstart
  %   {%
  %     \numberline
  %     {\LofPart {Part A, Figure\nobreakspace{}}{1}}%
  %     {\ignorespaces Caption of figure 1}%
  %   }%
  %   \Hy@toclinkend 
  #1{#2}{#3}{#4}{\rearrangeB #5}{#6}%
}%
\newcommand\rearrangeB[3]{%
  % #1 = \Hy@toclinkstart 
  % #2 = \numberline 
  %      {\LofPart {Part A, Figure\nobreakspace{}}{1}}%
  %      {\ignorespaces Caption of figure 1}%
  % #3 = \Hy@toclinkend 
  #1{\rearrangeC#2}#3%
}%
\newcommand\rearrangeC[3]{%
  % #1 = \numberline
  % #2 = \LofPart {Part A, Figure\nobreakspace{}}{1}
  % #3 = \ignorespaces Caption of figure 1
  #1{}{#2: #3}%
}%
\makeatother


\begin{document}
    
\newpage
\tableofcontents
    
\newpage
\listoffigures
\newpage
\listoftables

\newpage
\part{Structured Literature Review}

\section{Section One}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    {\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image}}
    \hfill
    \caption{Caption of figure 1}
    \label{fig1:Figure 1}
\end{figure}
    
\newpage
\part{Structured Literature Review}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    {\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image}} 
    \hfill
    \caption{Caption of figure 2}
    \label{fig2:Figure 2}
\end{figure}
    
\end{document}




You probably want the number of the part to be printed only in case it changed.
With TeXLive 2020, 2021, 2022 this might do the trick:
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,fleqn,english]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\graphicspath{%
    {../graphics/}%
}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=blue,
    urlcolor=blue,
    citecolor=blue
}

\makeatletter
\addtocontents{lof}{\string\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures}\protected@file@percent}%
\addtocontents{lot}{\string\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Tables}\protected@file@percent}%
\renewcommand\thepart{\Alph{part}}
\DeclareRobustCommand\LofLofPart[3]{#1#2#3}%
\DeclareRobustCommand\GobbleLofPart[3]{#3}%
\DeclareRobustCommand\LofPart[3]{#3}%
\addtocontents{lof}{\string\let\string\LofPart=\string\LofLofPart\protected@file@percent}%
\AtEndDocument{\addtocontents{lof}{\string\let\string\LofPart=\string\GobbleLofPart\protected@file@percent}}%
\renewcommand*\thefigure{\LofPart{Part \thepart}{\figurename~}{\arabic{figure}}}%
% Original definition:
%  \@dottedtocline{<number of sectioning level>}{<indenting>}{<width of number>}{<text>}{<page number>}%
%\renewcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline {1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}%
\renewcommand*\l@figure{\rearrange \@dottedtocline {1}{0em}{0em}}%
\newcommand\rearrange[6]{%
  % #1 = \@dottedtocline
  % #2 = number of sectioning level
  % #3 = indenting
  % #4 = width of number of figure
  % #5 = text
  % #6 = page number
  % ; text is of pattern
  %   \hyper@linkstart{link}{\Hy@tocdestname}%
  %   {%
  %     \numberline
  %     {\LofPart {Part A}{Figure\nobreakspace{}}{1}}%
  %     {\ignorespaces Caption of figure 1}%
  %   }%
  %   \hyper@linkend 
  #1{#2}{#3}{#4}{\rearrangeB #5}{#6}%
}%
\newcommand\rearrangeB[5]{%
  % #1 = \hyper@linkstart
  % #2 = link
  % #3 = \Hy@tocdestname
  % #4 = \numberline
  %      {\LofPart {Part A}{Figure\nobreakspace{}}{1}}%
  %      {\ignorespaces Caption of figure 1}%
  % #5 = \hyper@linkend
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\gdef
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\ThisPart
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\expandafter\ExtractSecondOffour\ExtractSecondOffour#4{}}%
  \ifx\PreviousPart\ThisPart\expandafter\hphantom\else\global\let\PreviousPart\ThisPart\expandafter\hbox\fi{\hbox to \PartWidth{\ThisPart\hss}}%
  #1{#2}{#3}{\rearrangeC #4}#5%
}%
\newcommand\rearrangeC[3]{%
  % #1 = \numberline
  % #2 = \LofPart {Part A}{Figure\nobreakspace{}}{1}
  % #3 = \ignorespaces Caption of figure 1
  #1{}{\ReplaceSecondoffour{}#2: #3}%
}%
\newcommand\ReplaceSecondoffour[5]{#2{#1}{#4}{#5}}%
\newcommand\ExtractSecondOffour[4]{#2}%
\newcommand\PreviousPart{\UnDeFinEDStartVALue}%
\newcommand\ThisPart{}%
\newlength\PartWidth
\addtocontents{lof}{\string\settowidth\string\PartWidth{Part W\string\hskip1em\string\null}\protected@file@percent}%
\makeatother


\begin{document}
    
\newpage
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\listoffigures
\newpage
\listoftables

\newpage
\part{Structured Literature Review}

\section{Section One}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    {\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image}}
    \hfill
    \caption{Caption of figure 1}
    \label{fig1:Figure 1}
\end{figure}

\section{Section Two}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    {\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image}}
    \hfill
    \caption{Caption of figure 2}
    \label{fig2:Figure 2}
\end{figure} 

\newpage
\part{Structured Literature Review}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    {\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image}} 
    \hfill
    \caption{Caption of figure 3}
    \label{fig3:Figure 3}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    {\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image}} 
    \hfill
    \caption{Caption of figure 4}
    \label{fig4:Figure 4}
\end{figure}

    
\end{document}


With TeXLive 2023, 2024 this might do the trick:
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,fleqn,english]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\graphicspath{%
    {../graphics/}%
}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=blue,
    urlcolor=blue,
    citecolor=blue
}

\makeatletter
\addtocontents{lof}{\string\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures}\protected@file@percent}%
\addtocontents{lot}{\string\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Tables}\protected@file@percent}%
\renewcommand\thepart{\Alph{part}}
\DeclareRobustCommand\LofLofPart[3]{#1#2#3}%
\DeclareRobustCommand\GobbleLofPart[3]{#3}%
\DeclareRobustCommand\LofPart[3]{#3}%
\addtocontents{lof}{\string\let\string\LofPart=\string\LofLofPart\protected@file@percent}%
\AtEndDocument{\addtocontents{lof}{\string\let\string\LofPart=\string\GobbleLofPart\protected@file@percent}}%
\renewcommand*\thefigure{\LofPart{Part \thepart}{\figurename~}{\arabic{figure}}}%
% Original definition:
%  \@dottedtocline{<number of sectioning level>}{<indenting>}{<width of number>}{<text>}{<page number>}%
%\renewcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline {1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}%
\renewcommand*\l@figure{\rearrange \@dottedtocline {1}{0em}{0em}}%
\newcommand\rearrange[6]{%
  % #1 = \@dottedtocline
  % #2 = number of sectioning level
  % #3 = indenting
  % #4 = width of number of figure
  % #5 = text
  % #6 = page number
  % ; text is of pattern
  %   \Hy@toclinkstart
  %   {%
  %     \numberline
  %     {\LofPart {Part A}{Figure\nobreakspace{}}{1}}%
  %     {\ignorespaces Caption of figure 1}%
  %   }%
  %   \Hy@toclinkend
  #1{#2}{#3}{#4}{\rearrangeB #5}{#6}%
}%
\newcommand\rearrangeB[3]{%
  % #1 = \Hy@toclinkstart
  % #2 = \numberline
  %      {\LofPart {Part A}{Figure\nobreakspace{}}{1}}%
  %      {\ignorespaces Caption of figure 1}%
  % #3 = \Hy@toclinkend
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\gdef
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\ThisPart
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\expandafter\ExtractSecondOffour\ExtractSecondOffour#2{}}%
  \ifx\PreviousPart\ThisPart\expandafter\hphantom\else\global\let\PreviousPart\ThisPart\expandafter\hbox\fi{\hbox to \PartWidth{\ThisPart\hss}}%
  #1{\rearrangeC #2}#3%
}%
\newcommand\rearrangeC[3]{%
  % #1 = \numberline
  % #2 = \LofPart {Part A}{Figure\nobreakspace{}}{1}
  % #3 = \ignorespaces Caption of figure 1
  #1{}{\ReplaceSecondoffour{}#2: #3}%
}%
\newcommand\ReplaceSecondoffour[5]{#2{#1}{#4}{#5}}%
\newcommand\ExtractSecondOffour[4]{#2}%
\newcommand\PreviousPart{\UnDeFinEDStartVALue}%
\newcommand\ThisPart{}%
\newlength\PartWidth
\addtocontents{lof}{\string\settowidth\string\PartWidth{Part W\string\hskip1em\string\null}\protected@file@percent}%
\makeatother


\begin{document}
    
\newpage
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\listoffigures
\newpage
\listoftables

\newpage
\part{Structured Literature Review}

\section{Section One}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    {\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image}}
    \hfill
    \caption{Caption of figure 1}
    \label{fig1:Figure 1}
\end{figure}

\section{Section Two}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    {\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image}}
    \hfill
    \caption{Caption of figure 2}
    \label{fig2:Figure 2}
\end{figure} 

\newpage
\part{Structured Literature Review}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    {\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image}} 
    \hfill
    \caption{Caption of figure 3}
    \label{fig3:Figure 3}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    {\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image}} 
    \hfill
    \caption{Caption of figure 4}
    \label{fig4:Figure 4}
\end{figure}

    
\end{document}



I get this error 'document.lof: error: 3: Argument of \rearrangeB has an extra }. ...}{1}}{\ignorespaces Figure 1}}{6}{figure.1}'

I get the error with both your original solution and the edited one. I use TexStudio with Biber

Thanks for this. How can I edit the code to allow the caption to reflect in the list of figures

thanks for adding the captions. The last version of the code you added is perfect.
